# Best way to insert rows into relational tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, linq, entity-framework

I have this code inside a click button event:

```
private void btn_addtodb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        stopwatch.Start();

        using (var context = new ScheduleDatabaseEntities())
        {
            foreach (string fullfilePath in ExcelfilesPath)
            {
                Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(fullfilePath);
                for (int i = 1; i <= theWorkbook.Worksheets.Count; i++)
                {
                    Excel.Worksheet theWorksheet = theWorkbook.Worksheets[i];
                    Excel.Range excelRange = theWorksheet.UsedRange;
                    object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
                    string teacherName = Convert.ToString(valueArray[9, 2]);

                    for (int k = 4; k <= 12; k = k + 2)
                    {
                        for (int j = 16; j <= 35; j = j + 2)
                        {
                            if (j == 24)
                                j--;
                            if (valueArray[j, k] != null)
                            {
                                int timeId = Convert.ToInt32(valueArray[j, 1]);
                                string startTime = Convert.ToString(valueArray[j, 2]);
                                string endTime = Convert.ToString(valueArray[j, 3]);
                                string room = Convert.ToString(valueArray[j, k + 1]);
                                string weekDay= Convert.ToString(valueArray[14, k]);
                                string sClass, subject;
                                string str = Convert.ToString(valueArray[j, k]);

                                if (Char.IsNumber(str[0]) && str.Contains(" "))
                                {
                                    string[] splistring = str.Split(new[] { " " }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
                                    sClass = splistring[0];
                                    subject = splistring[1];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sClass= null;
                                    subject = str;
                                }
                                context.Schedule.Add(new Schedule { TimeId= timeId , WeekDay= weekDay, SubjectId= FindSubjectId(subject), TeacherId= FindTeacherId(teacherName), RoomId= FindRoomId(room), ClassId= FindClassId(sClass) });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Done! Time: "+stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private int? FindSubjectId(string subject)
{
    using (var context = new ScheduleDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var findSubject = context.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Subject == subject);
        if (findSubject == null)
        {
            var subjectEntity = new Subjects { Subject= subject};
            context.Subjects.Add(subjectEntity);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return subjectEntity.SubjectId;
        }
        else
            return findSubject.SubjectId;
    }
}

private int? FindTeacherId(string teacher)
{
    using (var context = new ScheduleDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var findTeacher = context.Professores.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Professor == professor);
        if (findTeacher == null)
        {
            var teacherEntity = new Teachers{ Teacher = teacher};
            context.Professores.Add(teacherEntity);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return teacherEntity.TeacherId;
        }
        else
            return findTeacher.TeacherId;
    }
}

private int? FindRoomId(string room)
{
    using (var context = new ScheduleDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var findRoom = context.Rooms.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Room == room);
        if (findRoom == null)
        {
            var roomEntity = new Rooms{ Room = room};
            context.Rooms.Add(roomEntity);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return roomEntity.RoomId;
        }
        else
            return findRoom.RoomId;
    }
}

private int? FindClassId(string sClass)
{
    using (var context = new ScheduleDatabaseEntities())
    {
        if (sClass == null)
            return null;
        var findClass = context.Turmas.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Turma == turma);
        if (findClass  == null)
        {
            var classEntity = new Classes { Class = sClass};
            context.Classes.Add(classEntity);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return classEntity.ClassId;
        }
        else
            return findClass.ClassId;
    }
}
```

The problem is that executing this take a little more than I expected comparing with a single table insert (which was my previous version, but i guess doing relational tables was better for better organization), I know it will be slower inserting in different tables, but there isn't any solution to get this a little faster?

**Note**: The idea is to read some schedules files (in excel) from each teacher, and retrieve them to a database, for doing a class schedule from it. I already have the values that i want to insert to the database, so i have to insert in the relational tables and fill the row with that ID. I already had a version where this was fast, but was only a single table, which was a bad design (it was only for testing purposes). Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using a single context and saving only once at the end.

Comment: Just a quick question then, if I do that when I do the getId method again I will not have the updated table because I didn't SaveChanges(), or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm actually not certain about that for EF. You could try it?

Answer (score 0):

Persist your context from your apps start to finish then call Load on each dbset on the application start. This will load all the data into the local property in the dbset object. Then you can just use linq on that list because I believe calling context.Salas. will cause EF to query the database and generate the objects which is slower. Also then you wont have to create a new context on the button click.

```
//app start:
var context = new ScheduleDatabaseEntities();
context.Subjects.Load();

private async void ButtonEvent(...)
{
    int result = await FindSubjectId();
}

//button code
private async Task<int?> FindSubjectId(string subject)
{
        var findSubject = context.Subjects.Local.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Subject == subject);
        if (findSubject == null)
        {
            var subjectEntity = new Subjects { Subject= subject};
            context.Subjects.Add(subjectEntity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return subjectEntity.SubjectId;
        }
        else
            return findSubject.SubjectId;
    }
```

something like that. you can just make the FindSubjectId async void if you want and just call it normally in the button event.

Comment: Salas is suppose to be Rooms, i didn't translated that correctly. It was already edited, I will try the code, thx btw, i am really grateful.

Comment: If you have anymore questions let me know. I've been trying to improve EF performance myself.